# AnimatedCrossFade Widget not displaying text in release mode instead it displaying a grey background

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation, animatedcrossfade

```
AnimatedContainer(
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
          curve: Curves.easeIn,
          height: expandedStatus[index] ?300 : 160,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            boxShadow: const [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Color.fromARGB(168, 97, 97, 97),
                offset: Offset(2,2),
                blurRadius: 3,
                spreadRadius: 1,
              )
            ],
            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          ),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width-130,
                    child: Text(list[newIndex]['title'], style: _textTheme.headline6)
                  ),
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: () async {
                        expandedStatus.removeAt(newIndex);
                        int i = await DatabaseClass.instance
                            .delete(list[newIndex]['url']);
                        displayNews();
                      },
                    child: Container(
                      width: 40,
                      height: 40,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.pink,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)
                      ),
                      child: Icon(Icons.delete_outline_outlined)
                    )
                  )
                ],
              ),
                const SizedBox(height: 10),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                child: Text(
                  list[newIndex]['date'],
                  style: _textTheme.subtitle2,
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              AnimatedCrossFade(
                firstChild: Text("", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 0)),
                secondChild: (list[newIndex]['_description'] != "")  ?Flexible(child: Text(list[newIndex]['_description'].substring(0,list[newIndex]['_description'].length - 14), overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,maxLines: 5,style: _textTheme.subtitle1,)) :Text("Content Unavailable", style: _textTheme.subtitle1),
                crossFadeState: !expandedStatus[index] ?CrossFadeState.showFirst :CrossFadeState.showSecond,
                reverseDuration: Duration.zero,
                sizeCurve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn,
                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 800)
              )
            ],
          ),
        )
```

#### AnimatedCrossFade Widget not displaying text in release mode instead it displaying a grey background

Above code is working fine in the debugging mode, but in release mode the description text is vanished and a grey colored background is appeared. I'm not sure why is this happening. Please help.

### Release Mode

[image: release]

### Debug Mode

[image]

Comment: have you added internet permissions in android manifest file?

Comment: Yes, it's already added

Comment: update your question with your manifest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of your problem is the incorrect use of the Flexible widget.

Using flexible is wrong.

```
  AnimatedContainer(
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
              curve: Curves.easeIn,
              height: expandedStatus[index] ?300 : 160,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                boxShadow: const [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Color.fromARGB(168, 97, 97, 97),
                    offset: Offset(2,2),
                    blurRadius: 3,
                    spreadRadius: 1,
                  )
                ],
                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
              ),
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Row(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width-130,
                        child: Text(list[newIndex]['title'], style: _textTheme.headline6)
                      ),
                      InkWell(
                        onTap: () async {
                            expandedStatus.removeAt(newIndex);
                            int i = await DatabaseClass.instance
                                .delete(list[newIndex]['url']);
                            displayNews();
                          },
                        child: Container(
                          width: 40,
                          height: 40,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.pink,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)
                          ),
                          child: Icon(Icons.delete_outline_outlined)
                        )
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 10),
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                    child: Text(
                      list[newIndex]['date'],
                      style: _textTheme.subtitle2,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  AnimatedCrossFade(
                    firstChild: Text("", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 0)),
                    secondChild: (list[newIndex]['_description'] != "")  ? Column(children:[Flexible(child: Text(list[newIndex]['_description'].substring(0,list[newIndex]['_description'].length - 14), overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,maxLines: 5,style: _textTheme.subtitle1,))]) :Text("Content Unavailable", style: _textTheme.subtitle1),
                    crossFadeState: !expandedStatus[index] ?CrossFadeState.showFirst :CrossFadeState.showSecond,
                    reverseDuration: Duration.zero,
                    sizeCurve: Curves.fastLinearToSlowEaseIn,
                    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 800)
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )
```